# PHP split the text to the left and right base on the pattern

Tags: php, split

How to split the text to left and right of "."?

example:

string: **43.35**
left: 43
right: 35

string: **PHP.MYSQL**
left: PHP
right: MYSQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`list`](https://www.php.net/list) construct.

```
<?php
$str='PHP.MYSQL';
list($left,$right) = explode('.',$str);
echo $left;  // "prints" PHP
echo $right; // "prints" MYSQL
```

Answer (score 1):

so use explode.

```
$var="PHP.MYSQL";
$arr=explode('.',$var);
echo $arr[0];
echo $arr[1];
```